# Cannot type password when open notebook lid

Tags: login, suspend, power-management, laptop, login-screen

When I open the notebook lid, I see the screen before the login. The one which has some arrows pointing up so when I start typing or drag it to top, the password textbox will appear. But now, when I open the notebook, I see this screen without the arrows. When I press some key or try to drag the screen up, nothing happens. When I click in the up right corner (where wifi, sound and battery appears) there's only a "pause", o shutdown or restart button. When I press the pause button, the notebook sleeps again.

I have to force reboot and then it works.

**UPDATE: pitcure**

[image]

I discovered that doing control + alt + f1 send me to another screen where I can log in. But it's annoying to have to do that

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of the screen you are getting, that will be useful

Comment: @AvishekSaha I did. Take a look.

Comment: have you tried pressing the esc key?

Comment: @AvishekSaha I tried every key, nothing works